# Iron Man internal helmet effect

Tags: video, effects

Does Blender cater for this kind of visual effect: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=YD50NYOkyIg

in video files?

I can't find anything aside from Iron Man sculpture tutorials.

Comment: Of course, but it's hard work. You can search for *Iron Man HUD* or check out the latest making of: https://vimeo.com/66944464.

Comment: Lovely, thank you. Found this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QFJESgclikQ

Comment: Related: https://youtu.be/I3DSI_BjA4g, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IdUH3mqe9iE